# Function returns None when it should return the last index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, modulo

I'm trying to get this function to return the index of the smallest value in a list. It works for every case besides if the smallest value is the last element of the list. Can anyone spot my mistake?

```
def rotation_point(rotated_list):
  length = len(rotated_list)
  for i in range (0,length-1):
    if rotated_list[i]<rotated_list[(i+1)%length] and rotated_list[i]<rotated_list[i-1]:
      return i
    else:
      pass
```

I know it has something to do with the first part of the if statement, but I can't see why it wouldnt work.

Comment: Also it's important to know that the list has been sorted, but rotated by some amount (i.e. [2,3,4,5,1])

Comment: You're missing a `return` for that scenario. add `return length-1` after the `for loop`

Answer (score 1):

The if statement itself works just fine but you never actually check the last element because you use: `range(0,length-1)` for the range of the for loop. The `range` function already stops at `length - 1`. You should use: `range(0,length)`.

Note that you also don't really need the `0` since range already starts at zero by default, and there is no need for the `else: pass` since the use of an else statement is not required, removing it would change nothing.

This is what a working (and cleaner) version of your function would look like:

```py
def rotation_point(rotated_list):
  length = len(rotated_list)
  for i in range (length):
    if rotated_list[i]<rotated_list[(i+1)%length] and rotated_list[i]<rotated_list[i-1]:
      return i
```

Here are some more examples of the range function:

```py
>>> range(0, 5-1)
[0, 1, 2, 3]

>>> range(0, 5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `range(i, j)` goes from i to j - 1. Since you are using `range(0, length - 1)`, you are not traversing the entire array, just from the start to the second last index. A super easy fix is to add `return length - 1` to the end.

```
def rotation_point(rotated_list):
  length = len(rotated_list)
  for i in range (0,length-1):
    if rotated_list[i]<rotated_list[(i+1)%length] and rotated_list[i]<rotated_list[i-1]:
      return i
    else:
      pass
  return length - 1
```